Try to generate signed app bundle but getting error
Upgrade android project

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.5.2'

Then try to generate signed app bundle, but getting this error now:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PackageBundleTask$BundleToolWorkAction
File 'root/res/anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'.

